# Non static method cannot referenced - Inner class

Tags: class, variables, static, counter

```
        switch (position)

        {
            case 0:
                feld.setzeDeutsch();
                break;
```

This is a part of an Inner Class, but it says to make the setzeDeutsch method static.. I cant make this method static because there is a counter variable..
What can I do? Can I make the variable static?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an instance of the outer class to the inner class so that the inner class can access it. Do not make the variable static.

Comment: MainActivity.this.setzeDeutsch();

Comment: how can i do this?  MainActivity.this.setzeDeutsch(); I get the same error because of this.. thank you for your help

Comment: @antisepticum: Don't do that. Just pass an instance. If you don't know how to pass an instance, then you need more help than can be provided here- like the basics of your unspecified language.